# Taking norm of HUGE matrix in less than a second: NUMPY, PYTHON

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dense matrix of shape (1 000 000, 100). I want to take norms of all the rows. Currently I am using

```
import numpy
a =  numpy.random.rand((1000000,100))
b = numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis =1) # this takes 2.78 seconds.
```

Is there a way that I can reduce this time to take norms?

Comment: which numpy version are you using? it takes 500ms with my amd phenom2 and numpy 1.8.1 (amd64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a smaller `dtype`;

```
In [8]: a = numpy.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [9]: %timeit numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop

In [11]: b = numpy.asarray(a, numpy.float32)

In [12]: %timeit numpy.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.5 ms per loop
```

Using an optimized or parallelized LAPACK library *might* also help, depending on the numpy version.

Using numpy with ATLAS on a Intel Core2 Quad (Q9300) running FreeBSD 10 amd64 I get:

```
In [14]: a =  numpy.random.rand(1000000,100)

In [15]: %timeit -n 10 numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis =1)
10 loops, best of 3: 1.08 s per loop
```

There is one other way to speed thinkgs up, assuming you have a multi-core machine;

- Write the array to a file
- Write a function to read a certain row from that file, square and sum all the numbers and return the result.
- Use `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` to run this function in multiple processes.
- When `map()` returns, sum the resulting list and take the square root of that sum.

The speed-up should be approximately equal to the number of available cores.

Comment: np.linalg.norm as of 1.9 does not use BLAS/ATLAS, its just sqrt(sum(x.conj()*x))

Comment: I have ATLAS installed. I am running this on Ubuntu with single core and 4GB RAM. Do you think other specifications might help?

Comment: 4 GB should be plenty.

Comment: there is no need to use multiprocessing, threading is enough, numpy releases the GIL during these operations. But as mentioned in my answer the memory allocator might get in the way. memory bandwidth is also a problem for this case so you are unlikely to get linear scaling beyond 2-3 cores.

Answer (score 2):

the simple norm is a memory bound problem which are not very efficient with numpy.
The numpy-only way of improving it is doing some blocking to avoid going over data multiple times:

```
import numpy as np
a =  np.random.rand(1000000,100)
print np.linalg.norm(a, axis =1).shape

def g(d, out=None):
    bs = 2000
    if out is None:
        r = np.empty(d.shape[0])
    else:
        r = out
    for i in range(0, d.shape[0], bs):
        u = min(i + bs, d.shape[0])
        r[i:u] = np.linalg.norm(d[i:u], axis=1)
    return r


print  (g(a) == numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis =1)).all()
print "blocked"
%timeit -n 10 g(a)
print "normal"
%timeit -n 10 numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis =1)
```

On my machine (DDR2 ram) with numpy 1.9 this results in a modest improvement:

```
blocked
10 loops, best of 3: 294 ms per loop
normal
10 loops, best of 3: 561 ms per loop
```

adding another layer of blocking using threads should in principle improve performance a bit more, but on my machine (glibc 2.19) this leads to excessive page faulting due to glibc trimming the heap to often in threaded mode, so it doesn't actually help.

```
strace -f  -e madvise ipython test_threaded.ipy 2>&1  | grep MADV_DONTNEED -c
14228
```

Comment: Which LAPACK library does your numpy use?

Comment: np.linalg.norm as of 1.9 does not use BLAS/ATLAS, its just sqrt(sum(x.conj()*x))